# Is geofire version 2.3.0 incompatible with play-service-location version 11.8.0?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm working on a location tracking application and when I try to save a user's live location coordinates online via geofire, I use this particular piece of code,

```
        String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");

        GeoFire geofire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geofire.setLocation(user_id, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
```

Now my app crashes due to the code portion containing "GeoFire" initialization and use.

What's going on here, Is it due to incompatibility ?

Comment: Please add your entire error.

Comment: there isn't any error. Only the app quits after some time @AlexMamo

Comment: If it crashes, it crashes with an error. What is the error from your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

```
        //using Geofire
    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driversAvailable");

    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    geoFire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

or change geoFire to 2.1.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks